# Place a comment on a specific PHP post with a postID

Tags: php

I'm doing a project for school, it is some similar as Instagram. So you can post a photo on your timeline and then other users can place a comment on this photo.
This comment option is succesfully done: You can place a comment on a photo and the comment comes into the database.

But now the problem is:

- The comment on a photo comes on every post and not on the specific post? 
  Now i will link a post with a postID but this postID will not come in my database, only the comment comes in my database.

CODES:

[comment.class.php](http://pastie.org/10819886)

[Picture Database classe click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5PFZ.png)

Comment: $c_iPostID in Save method is exist or not? Problem probably will be at calling method Save

Comment: Post the code in the question. Please don't make me go to some site that's going to try and serve me ads and stuff to try to and help you.

Answer (score 0):

In line 64 you are missing colon from your prepare statement:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO comment(userID, postID, 
comment) VALUES(:userID, :PostID, :comment)');
```

You have userID, should be :userID

Comment: this is not the solution of my problem. When i use :userid en :post:id in the query the comment didn't come in the database when i use only :comment in the query then comes the post in de db.